# Reset pagesize for each record iText

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, itext

I am trying to reset the pagesize of each record in pdf, which is the total page

```
(1 of pagesize
 2 of pagesize.......)
```

The 1st blockcode work for 1 single record but then when it come to multiple record it showed:

```
1 of 0     //1st record
2 of 0
1 of 0     //2nd record
```

.......

I think there is something to do with ***document.setPageSize()*** but it is boolean and belong to Rectangle.

Please help me solve this problem.
Thank.

---

```
Public Overrides Sub onEndPage(ByVal writer As PdfWriter, ByVal document As Document)

    Dim page As Rectangle = document.getPageSize()
    Dim cb As PdfContentByte = writer.getDirectContent()
    Dim arialbasefont As BaseFont = arial.getBaseFont
    Dim pg As Rectangle = document.getPageSize()

    Dim pageNumberText As String = "Page " & writer.getPageNumber() & " of "
    Dim timeStampText As String = Now.ToString
    Dim pageNumberTextLength As Double = arialbasefont.getWidthPoint(pageNumberText, footerFontSize)
    Dim timeStampTextLength As Double = arialbasefont.getWidthPoint(timeStampText, footerFontSize)
    Dim pageNumberTextLeft As Double = 20
    Dim templateLeft As Double = pageNumberTextLeft + pageNumberTextLength
    Dim pageNumberTextBottom As Double = 5 + footerFontSize

    cb.beginText()
    cb.setFontAndSize(arialbasefont, footerFontSize)
    cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, pageNumberText, pageNumberTextLeft, pageNumberTextBottom, 0)
    cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, Now, pg.urx - (timeStampTextLength + 20), pageNumberTextBottom, 0)
    cb.endText()
    cb.addTemplate(tpl, templateLeft, pageNumberTextBottom)

End Sub
```

---

For Each ProjectID In array

```
                Dim rptRequestReportObj As New rptRequestReport2
                rptRequestReportObj.Report(document, ProjectID)

                document.newPage()
                document.setPageCount(1)
```

Next ProjectID

Comment: I think you misunderstand iText `PageSize`; that is not the number of pages but the dimensions of the page.

Comment: however it showed total page if i just print a record. 
Don't you get my question tho?

Comment: What does your question have to do with VBA? Shouldn't you have chosen the VB.NET tab? Please click "edit" below your question and correct the tags so that the right people see it...

Comment: You don't show when and with what your code fills `tpl`.